# How to use ES6-symbol polyfill

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, polyfills

I have an Symbol is not defined in IE so I tried to use this library as polyfill

```
https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol
```

As inexperienced as I am, I do not really know how to include it so that it use as global.
In detail, in my code I include it using requirejs as:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: 
     {  'symbol': 'libs/es6-symbol/index'    }
 })

//define it in app entry point

require([
    'symbol'],
 function (sy) {
             //What should I do?
              }
```

How should i approach this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just load the `index.js` of `es6-symbol` with RequireJS. If you just look at it, you'll see:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('./is-implemented')() ? Symbol : require('./polyfill');
```

This is valid `CommonJS` code but not valid AMD code. RequireJS supports AMD natively, not `CommonJS`. To use `CommonJS` code with RequireJS you'd have *at a minimum* to wrap the code above in a `define` call, which means having a build step.

Ultimately, you should heed the advice of the [README](https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol):

> To port it to Browser or any other (non CJS) environment, use your favorite CJS bundler. No favorite yet? Try: Browserify, Webmake or Webpack

Research the bundlers, pick one, write a build configuration for it, and if you still have trouble you can ask on this site.

Comment: I am not really good with this, but to my understanding from above, it means that there is no simple way to load polyfill (like include as script)? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: @LoredraL It's quite simple to load, you just need to devote those 5-10 minutes (one time job) to get accustomed how to create needed bundle.
e.g. with webmake it should be as easy as running following three commands in console: Install bundler (globally): `npm install -g webmake`, install es6-symbol (in current dir): `npm install es6-symbol`,  Create a bundle: `webmake es6-symbol/implement.js es6-symbol.bundle.js`. Then you need just to load `es6-symbol.bundle.js` in your HTML (prior loading scripts that rely on it)